# bipolar linear hall effect sensor choice

Tags: arduino, electromagnetism, linear, hall-effect

ANSWER: This is the best one I found for my purpose mouser.be/new/Texas-Instruments/ti-drv5053-hall-effect-sensor

I'm doing a project where I use Hall effect sensor as a proximity meter.

Using to (electro)magnets opposing each other to know a certain data when their in rest or in active state? 
The states between 2 (electro)magnets are then : 1-1, 1-0,0-1,0-0 or S-S, S-N, N-S, N-N.

But my arduino should get the data from the hall sensor between the magnets and give a digital or analog input that I can then reroute to MAX/MSP.

The sensors I've bought aren't really good I guess because the value isn't significant much.

The type I have is the US5881LUA => [info](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/US5881_rev007.pdf) this is unipolar, and I would like to have a bipolar one, or a way to get both sides of the magnetic poles that it gets from the 2 magnets.

QUESTIONS:

1. Is there a more accurate sensor on the market.
2. Do I have to use an other type of sensor for this.
3. Is this project possible in theory.
4. Did anybody try to read the data from it to an arduino and do this want to share their experience.

[image: nice drawing of my interpretation ^^]

Comment: I'm confused by what you are trying to do.  Put a link to your device.  http://www.melexis.com/prodfiles/0004824_US5881_rev008.pdf  The spec sheet title lists it as a low sensitivity switch, so the sensor is built in.  This app note is also nice.. (I only skimmed it.) http://www.melexis.com/prodfiles/0003715_hallapps.pdf

Comment: From what I get in my question is that the one I have has too low sensitivity. And I think I should have high sensitivity. Correct me if I'm wrong.
Also the one I mentioned has the same app sheet as yours and it has similar specs as the one I have.
Last it's a unipolar one. 
But I'll give a link from the one I have, for not getting misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bipolar sensor (I've had good experiences with Allegro sensors), but I think using the construction that you're drawing to detect 4 states is going to be difficult. A bipolar sensor is only going to give a signed magnetic field strength value. Determining what combination of magnet states is active right now would only be possible if the sensor isn't perfectly in the middle between them / or they're of different strength. You'd then have to record observed values in all 4 states, and hope that they're different enough to discern.

Comment: The sensor doesn't have to be in the middle.

I'm hoping that when N-S or S-N the magnets will 'smash' to each other. When that happens I want the magnet to sense the magnitude or magnetic current in the air of both of them.
So when N-N or S-S is a state the magnets revoke each other and then the sensor will sense on each side the opposite magnetic field and that value it gets from the magnet should be processed thru arduino.

Comment: i don't think it works that way, but i don't know enough to be more specific.

Comment: Well this video shows, in the last part of it the linear sensor. The led reacts on the magnet. So it gets data and with that data I should be able to do more. This in theory is correct. Though I just don't know the bipolar part of it. Hopefully somebody does. Thanks for trying to help me though![link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHB1m9UMi0s)

Comment: You really need to clarify your question. The video shows how a linear hall effect sensor works - it produces a voltage proportional to the magnetic field strength it sees. The two magnet setup you're trying to measure, however, is a different beast, and I'm not sure that the combined magnetic field looks like you think it does.

Comment: Hey did some more research and stumbled on this type of sensor from TI, High accurate and bipolar. 
They give a video example of usage. And this one shows a north and south pole activity.[link]http://www.mouser.be/new/Texas-Instruments/ti-drv5053-hall-effect-sensor/  

I thought if a place two of them pointed at opposite sides I should get either N or S on one sensor and same for the other sensor thats positioned in the other direction? Or doesn't it work like that? 

I thought of maybe asking an admin to relocate this to the physics stackexchange. But don't know how.